# Django ManyRelatedManager filtering based on through class

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a simple many-to-many relationship based around a through class.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Friendship')

class Friendship(models.Model):
    me = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    them = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This should, in short, allow somebody to add somebody else as a friend, but the link doesn't exist until the other person confirms it. Simple enough.

I want to add a `is_friend(self, user)` method to `Person`. In that I want to do something like:

```
is_friend(self, user):
    return self.friends.filter(them=user, confirmed=True).count()
```

But `filter` only seems to operate on the distant class (in this case `Person`). Is there any way I can filter on `Friendship` instead while still using the `ManyRelatedManager`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit rusty, but have you tried `return Friendship.objects.filter(me=self, them=user, confirmed=True)`?

Comment: I have, and yes, this works... I just expected providing a "through" class to give me some shortcuts or database savings. I have other queries in other places that are a lot more complicated than this that would need a query-able shortcut to stop them turning into monstrous, multiple nested queries.

Comment: You could save many database queries if you use select_related() in your queryset to retrieve the person, so it won't hit the database again when retrieving its friends

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
is_friend(self, user):
    return self.friends.filter(friendship__them=user, friendship__confirmed=True).count()
```